# does running linux off a usb drive require a proper functioning internal hard disk

Tags: boot, hard-drive, live-usb

I have a laptop with windows 7 installed on it. Somehow my internal hard disk failed and now windows wont boot anymore(it wont let me repair or install a new copy of windows). So i tried to run Linux off a USB pen drive. However after a few messages the laptop hangs with a blank screen. I was just wondering if i need a fully functional internal hard-disk to run Linux off a pendrive

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No.

Ubuntu will happily run from a USB drive without any other drives present.

Comment: any idea on how to know where the ubuntu stops loading so i might know where the problem really lies?