# Is an internal hdd required to "try ubuntu from disk"?

Tags: hard-drive, lubuntu

I have an old laptop (Thinkpad T60 4gb ram, intel duo core 2.16ghz cpu) that does not have a hard drive in it. I want to test it out before buying a hard drive for it.

I used pen drive usb installer to install ubuntu 13.10, ubuntu 12.04, and lubuntu 13.10 on separate usb (4gb) drives and booted from them. Then I tried them before installing. Each on hangs. Lubuntu got the furthest. It opened up to the desktop but then immediately froze.

Could this be a problem solved by installing a hard drive?

Thanks!

edit: So as soon as I submitted this I found a [similar quesion.](https://askubuntu.com/questions/324984/does-running-linux-off-a-usb-drive-require-a-proper-functioning-internal-hard-di?rq=1) It still does not answer what the problem might actually be. Any help would still be appreciated.

Comment: How did you "install" ubuntu onto the usb device. Did you use something like UnetBootin, or did you simply choose a partition on that drive when running an *actual* install of Ubuntu? If you did that latter, there's your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can run a live usb or live cd without a HDD installed. There maybe other issues with the computer causing the system to hang. Are there mismatched RAM sticks in the machine? Or is there the possibility that the CPU is overheating, perhaps new thermal paste on the heatsink? There are a number of hardware issues that can cause this sort of issue, but in general a live USB does not need an internal HDD.

Comment: Thanks! I guess Ill take it apart to check for some of these problems.

Comment: If the HDD is still in the machine but has just failed - try disconnecting it completely, as it might be trying to read and utilize the defective disk.

Comment: There is no HDD installed at all

Comment: Then its back to checking what I mentioned in my original answer, I thought I would mention it just in case it was still in there. Anyways best of luck, let us know how you get on.